# how to count number of child for AEM Node?

Tags: java, aem, sling

I have node inside CRXDE /content/dam/assets/ar_sa/Marketing/Collateral-Program/2016/4/c05085279
 I need to get count of child nodes inside c05085279 folder.. is there any way to get that

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Resource AssetRes=resolver.getResource(updatedAsset);
Iterator<Resource> iterator= AssetRes.listChildren();
int count= 0;
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    count++;
    iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: AEM internally exposes Guava library you could simply do - `Iterators.size(iterator);`